# Linear Transformation vs Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Axler's book, and I'm struggling a little bit with the "think in terms of operators" and "compute in terms of matrices". Many times, someone asks a question about matrices, and I'd like to be able to answer in terms of operators, instead of matrix proofs. I'll give two examples of what I mean. In the first example, I'd like to know if my general thought process is correct. In the second example, I'd appreciate it if someone could explain if I'm on the right track or not and maybe fill in the missing piece:

Example 1: Suppose you have a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. To prove that it has at least one real eigenvalue, I'd resort to the fact that any non-zero $T:V\to V$ operator on a finite and odd dimensional, $\mathbb{R}$ vector space $V$ has at least one real eigenvalue. Since $A$ (and all matrices similar to it) represent a particular operator $T$ on a $3$-dim real vector space, and since operators and their matrix representations have the same eigenvalues, it follows that $A$ has at least one real eigenvalue. Is this the right idea?

Example 2: I'd like to prove that a real symmetric matrix has only real eigenvalues, using facts about operators. If an operator $T$ is self-adjoint, it has only real eigenvalues. It also follows that if $T$ is self-adjoint on a real vector space, and I fix a basis in the domain and codmain vector spaces (each of dim$=n$), then the matrix representation $A$ of $T$ in this basis is symmetric: $A=A^T$. However, I'm starting from the fact that $A=A^T$ and trying to conclude real eigenvalues, so the logic is kind of reversed. I need $A=A^T\implies T$ is self-adjoint, which I'm not sure if this is true.

Comment: An operator is self adjoint on a real space if and only if its matrix with respect to some (equivalently any) orthonormal basis is symmetric.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you. I think my book only had the one direction, so I wasn't sure

Comment: The matrix-free definition of self-adjoint is: Any endomorphism $T$ on a finite dimensional (for simplicity) and real (for simplicity) inner product space $V$ has an adjoint, namely an endomorphism $S$ on $V$ with $(Tx,y)=(x,Sy)$, for all $x,y\in V$. Moreover, $S$ is unique. $T$ is self adjoint if $T=S$. From here, and the definition for complex vector spaces you can easily give a matrix-free proof of 2).